# Why Doesn't load JavaScript in Joomla

Tags: javascript, joomla

I mostly work with PHP and don't have much experience with JavaScript or Joomla. I have  [website](https://pramo.lt) made in Joomla, but it doesn't load JS(only just loads rocket.min.js) on the desktop, but it works on mobile. Maybe there is a simple solution? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you trying to load a js file in your header or into a specific component or module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your website just loads rocket.min.js in joomla, you have to consider to turn off Cloudflare Rocket Loader™ BETA. It helps me as a charm.